# How to exclude specific directory from wildcard in logrotate?

Tags: regex, apache, logrotate

I've got the following problem: I've got a webserver with ~50 website on it, and everyone got it's own directory under `/var/www/*sitename*`, e.g. `/var/wwww/example.org/`.

In those directories there are a log folder and a htdocs folder, so the apache config looks like this:

```
[...]
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/htdocs
CustomLog /var/www/example.org/logs/access.log combined
ErrorLog /var/www/example.org/logs/error.log
[...]
```

This is the same for all the websites, to make sure the logs rotate I copied the content `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` into the same file, but adjusted the path like this: `/var/www/*/logs/*.log`, standard is this: `/var/log/apache2/*.log`.

So this logrotate applies to all websites, but now my problem is: one specific website (and maybe more in the future) should not rotate everyday, but weekly. And not 14 times then, but e.g. 4 times.

I've tried a lot now to achieve this, but I cannot get it working.
I created the folders test1 and test2 and made some access.log files.
logrotate conf looks like this:

```
/var/log/apache2/test*/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 14
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
                fi;
        endscript
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
}

/var/log/apache2/[!t][!e][!s][!t][!2]*/*.log {}
```

In my understanding this should rotate the log file in test1/ but not in test2/, but it's not working, the wildcard rule from above still applies.

Comment: I assume you know the dangers of putting log files inside the document root and have applied approriate protections?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it also be possible to use this:

`/var/log/apache2/[!test2]*/*.log {}`

Answer (score -1):

Try moving this rule to the top and check if it helps.

```
/var/log/apache2/[!t][!e][!s][!t][!2]*/*.log {}
```